# DeepAR model testing without Deploying

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am training DeepAR model for time series forecasting and after training I need to deploy that model to an end point for testing purposes.

Can I get forecasting in my notebook without deploying to an endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

If endpoints don't work for you, you can use batch transform, which will predict data stored in S3, and output results in S3 as well. Doc at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-batch.html

This is super simple, and will look something like:

```
batch_input = 's3://{}/{}/test/examples'.format(bucket, prefix)
batch_output = 's3://{}/{}/batch-inference'.format(bucket, prefix) 

transformer = model.transformer(instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge', output_path=batch_output)

transformer.transform(data=batch_input, data_type='S3Prefix', content_type='text/csv', split_type='Line')

transformer.wait()
```

If local deployment is what you're looking for, it's not available for built-in algos, only for built-in frameworks (TF, MXNet, etc.).

Comment: Yes, its not working for built-in algos like DeepAR. I am getting this exception AttributeError: 'DeepARPredictor' object has no attribute 'transformer'

Comment: Batch transform is totally supported, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/deepar-in-formats.html#deepar-batch. Something must be wrong with your code, can you post it?

Comment: From the error, it seems like you are invoking the method from a predictor object. This predictor object would be returned from the Python SDK after the .deploy() method invocation. You'd have to call the transformer method on a object of the Estimator class